# Save array in Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

I have Dim a(15) as integer i wont to save this array in Viewstate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to assign this variable to ViewState with a given key. Note that when you attempt to access the variable, you will need to cast it to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

Save it like this:-

```
ViewState("MyArray") = a
```

Access it like this:-

```
a = CType(ViewState("MyArray"), Integer())
```

I'm a C# guy might be mistaking in VB.NET code. Please do correct me.

Comment: Does't need to cast ViewState("MyArray")